# Remove every <br /> except one per line?

Tags: php, regex

How can I turn this:

```
...<br />
<br />
...<br />
...<br />
<br />
<br />
...<br />
```

Into this using **PHP**:

```
...<br />
...<br />
...<br />
...
```

Please notice the deletion of the first and last 
 even if it's mentioned once. In the middle we keep just one

Comment: [Friends don't let friends parse HTML with regular expressions.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: @Ether While I agree in general, this isn't really parsing HTML, just squeezing duplicate strings.

Comment: @Daniel: never seen a `<br style="clear:both;">` for instance? <br>'s can have all sorts of attributes just as easily.

Comment: @Wrikken as a matter of fact I have (see my answer ;) ). Duplicate really should have been in quotes though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
preg_replace('#<br />(\s*<br />)+#', '<br />', $your_string);
```

This will replace instances of more than one `<br />`, optionally with whitespace separating them, with a single `<br />`.

Note that `<br />` in the pattern matches exactly that. If you wanted to be more defensive, you could change it to `<br[^>]*>` which would allow for `<br>` tags that have attributes (ie. `<br style="clear: both;" />`) or that don't have the trailing slash.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should edit your question because the first `<br />` doesn't appear.

Then to replace all duplicate `<br />` AND the first and the last one, you can do :

```
$str = <<<EOD
<br />
...<br />
<br />
...<br />
...<br />
<br />
<br />
...<br />
EOD;

$str = preg_replace('~(^<br />\s*)|((?<=<br />)\s*<br />)|(<br />\s*$)~', '', $str);
echo "===\n",$str,"\n===\n";
```

This will output:

```
===
...<br />
...<br />
...<br />
...
===
```